# better way to process records, select and update lock

Tags: java, sql, select, locking

I had a problem in my software that sometimes caused a lock on the SQL server.

This was caused by a process that selects a group of records and starts processing them.

Based on some values and a calculation the records get updated.

When a record is being updated the page where that record is on, is locked by the SQL server for select. Which results in a lock that never solves itself.

To solve the problem we have created a second table, from which we select, the main table is copied into it before the process starts, the table that is updated is not being selected in that way and no lock can appear.

What I am looking for is simple and better solution for this problem, because for me it is like a workaround for something I'm doing the wrong way and would really like to improve the processing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change **TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL** on database. Here is [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx).

Comment: Thank you will read on that, but is this the regular way to deal with this kind of problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your default isolation level is set to repeatable read, which causes the select to set a shared lock on the returned records, deadlock happens when concurrent requests come in. To solve this you should take a locking select (to lock records with X lock rather than S lock).

Comment: The actual lock is LOCK_IX

Comment: Yes, before a transaction can acquire an X lock on a row, it must first acquire an IX lock on the table. take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-lock-modes.html